# How to detect a parent component is rendered in the DOM from child components

Tags: reactjs

I have several child components that need to be styled once the parent has rendered. The styling is position and size related and calculated by determining the parent components height/width in the page. Therefore I need the parent component rendered before I can style the child components.

I can't have the child components part of the parent component.

I tried using a ref on the parent component, and then triggering a props.onItemRendered() callback on each item component during componentDidMount() but i have found that the parent component calls componentDidMount() after all child components have mounted - therefore my parent item ref is null.

How should I get around this? I'm out of ideas

Comment: You can't make the child component part of the parent component? This does not look like a parent-children relationship, are your components siblings?

Comment: Please provide Parent and child component code details

Comment: The best would be to avoid relying on DOM entirely. Refs adds lots of complexity and potential bugs to react apps, and if there is any other way to solve your problem, avoid ref and direct dom manipulation.

Comment: @R.Duteil the child components are passed in by users and there is an unknown amount - I merely add positioning

Comment: Could you add some code so we can find out how your app is working ?

Comment: @HåkenLid how would I style positioning without inspecting the DOM? I need to know things such as what padding, margin, border etc is set to calculate it

Comment: The best way is to leave style positioning to the browser. Using css. But your question is not really answerable since we know nothing at all about your app, except the fact that it's broken. So add a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Children aren't rendered until the parent is rendered. If you never render the parent, then the children will never be rendered.

You can use percentage CSS values on the children, it will be relative to the parent.

Something like this:

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px dashed white;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <div id='child'></div>
</div>
```